# Data extraction and conversion of a NetCDF File

Tags: plot, type-conversion, gnuplot, netcdf, ferret

Hey Guys I am using Ferret in order to look at some data stored in NetCDF files.
However, I am only able to plot the data along all the measured values: Ferret plots data from 1998 to 2004. Since I wasn't to be able to focus on a single year period; however Ferret won't let me adjust the axis range so I wanted to now try to extract the data points into a .txt or .dat file so that I could use GNUPlot to look at them.
Here is the data stored in the file:

```
yes? show dat
'''currently SET data sets:
    1> ./CrawfordPoint_surface.nc  (default)
 name     title                             I         J         K         L
 T_2M     Air temperature at 2 m           ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 T_2M_O   Origin of air temperature data   ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 RH_2M    Relative humidity at 2 m         ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 RH_2M_O  Origin of relative humidity dat  ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 WS_10M   Wind speed at 10 m               ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 WS_10M_O Origin of wind speed data        ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 P        Snowfall rate                    ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 P_O      Origin of snowfall rate          ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 SRIN     Downward shortwave radiation     ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 SRIN_O   Origin of downward shortwave ra  ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 SROUT    Upward shortwave radiation       ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 SROUT_O  Origin of the upward shortwave   ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 LRIN     Downward longwave radiation      ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 LROUT    Upward longwave radiation        ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 SHF      Sensible heat flux               ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 LHF      Latent heat flux                 ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 G        Subsurface heat flux             ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 TS       Surface temperature              ...       ...       ...       1:105193
 MELT     Melt rate                        ...       ...       ...       1:105193
```

I can look individually at the data sets by asking Ferret to list it:

```
yes? list TS
             VARIABLE : Surface temperature (K)
             FILENAME : CrawfordPoint_surface.nc
             SUBSET   : 105193 points (TIME)
 01-JUN-1998 00:00:00 /      1:  265.2
 01-JUN-1998 01:00:00 /      2:  264.4
 01-JUN-1998 01:59:59 /      3:  263.7
 01-JUN-1998 03:00:00 /      4:  263.1
...
```

Each of these files has time data of several years, I would like to be able to look at (say: Surface temp) over a single year rather than asking Ferret to plot it ( `yes? PLOT TS`) which plots all of it. Reason why I was advised to try using gnuplot. However, it cannot read those files directly (netCDF).

Kind regards to everyone, please help.

Comment: Please, post a snippet from the data.

Comment: Hey, just edited the question. I hope it is more clear now!

Comment: Sorry, the question is still unclear. The dots in column I, J, and K are just
placeholders? Column L has all the same values? I don't see any date or year. There is nothing to plot here. Do you want to plot all values in one row?

Comment: Seems like your files have some very specify internal format (https://ferret.pmel.noaa.gov/Ferret/documentation/users-guide/data-set-basics/NETCDF-DATA, http://test.opendap.org/opendap/data/nc/test.nc). Gnuplot can plot binary files (http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/plot.html#binary), but one needs to know format, byte offset, etc.

Comment: Is there any commands to do the export within ferret or should i list the data, and copy-paste it into a .txt or .dat file

Comment: I don't know ferret. Gnuplot works well with dat and csv files and with data stored in columns, though there are also workarounds for row formatted data (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685656, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563953).

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the data in such a format into a text file then your almost done.
Although, the date format `01-JUN-1998` is a bit special. But I guess since gnuplot 5.0.3 it can be read as input. Check `help time_specifiers`.
Even if you have all the years in your data you can simply limit it to 1998 only if you set the xrange in gnuplot accordingly. Column separator by default is whitespace, so your data values are in column 5.

**Data:** `Data.dat`

```
             VARIABLE : Surface temperature (K)
             FILENAME : CrawfordPoint_surface.nc
             SUBSET   : 105193 points (TIME)
 01-JUN-1998 00:00:00 /      1:  265.2
 01-JUN-1998 01:00:00 /      2:  264.4
 01-JUN-1998 01:59:59 /      3:  263.7
 01-JUN-1998 03:00:00 /      4:  263.1
 03-JUN-1998 00:00:00 /      4:  260.0
```

**Code:**

```
### print time data with abbreviated month
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d-%b" time

set xrange [strptime(myTimeFmt,"01-JUN-1998"):strptime(myTimeFmt,"03-JUN-1998")]
set style line 1 pt 7 lc rgb "red"

plot 'Data.dat' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):5 w lp ls 1 ti "Surface temperature (K)"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: So do I just copy and paste all the data after I ask Ferret to display it on my screen? Or how do I get FERRET to save a text file of the netCDF file?

Comment: I don't know Ferret, and whether it has an option to save data as a file. But if you can list the data on the screen, well, then YOU have to copy and save the data into a file.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, just wanted to make sure. Thank you!