# gnuplot: How to plot y:row1 and x:row2 from csv

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot

I have a question about ploting graphics with gnuplot.

I have a .csv file, the **first row** has to be the **y axis** and the **second row** has to be the **x axis**

This is the `file.csv`

```
7.88, 7.26, 61.89, 7.00, 6.92, 6.96, 7.42
3,    4,     5,    6,    7,    8,    9
```

and this the code:

```
set datafile separator comma
plot 'file.csv' using 2:xtic(1) notitle with boxes
```

There are examples for plotting row-wise, but these examples do not cover this case or are using an external tool for reformatting of the data.

Using gnuplot matrix (cannot be used in this case):

[Plot csv file with multiple rows using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51031427/7295599)

[Plotting .csv data by row with GNUplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43368863/7295599)

Reformatting (awk and an unspecified tool):

[how plot per rows in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42798049/7295599)

[Gnuplot: Plot row-wise and named data as bundle of differently colored and titled lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33563953/7295599)

Can this maybe nevertheless be achieved with gnuplot only?

Comment: Please don't post data and code as picture. Please insert it as text.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please check the acceptance mark at the answer. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Plotting data which is arranged in rows is a recurring question or demand for gnuplot.

The short answer is: gnuplot doesn't like data in rows and prefers having it organized in columns.
So, simply transpose your data. Unfortunately, gnuplot does not have a transpose function.
What (gnuplot and Linux) people would say: use an external tool (e.g. awk, sed, ...) and prepare your data in such a way (here: transpose) that gnuplot can easily plot it.

If you want to do it with gnuplot only, the links (I added to your question) do not help since your "special" case with y-values in one row and x-values in another row is not covered.

That's why I want to suggest another "obscure" *gnuplot-only* solution and therefore platform independent and independent of additional installations.

This solution probably can be tuned to cover more than 2 rows.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### plotting data from two rows
reset session

$Data <<EOD
7.88, 7.26, 61.89, 7.00, 6.92, 6.96, 7.42
3.1,  4.2,   5.3,  6.4,  7.5,  8.6,  9.7
EOD

set datafile separator comma
stats $Data u 0 nooutput    # get the number of columns in STATS_columns
set datafile missing "nan"
set datafile separator whitespace

set table $DataXY
    plot for [col=1:STATS_columns] v1=NaN $Data u (v0=v1,v1=column(col)):(v0) w table
unset table

plot $DataXY u 1:2 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I have the next errors:
Line 9: Command not found
Line 17: stats: Command not found
Line 20: syntax error near unexpected token ('

Line 9 is $Data <<EOD
Line 17 is stats $Data nooutput    
Line 20 is (int($0)?a=column(col):b=column(col),sprintf("%g,%g",a, b)) w table

Thank you

Comment: The above code is copy&paste code, it should work with gnuplot >=5.2. Which version of gnuplot are you running? Can you edit your question and post your actual code? Skip the `$Data ... EOD` section and replace `$Data` in line 12 with `"file.csv"`. Eventually with the full path.